# Issue in moving files between folders in EC2 Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, python-watchdog

I have been working on a system where I have a python script in EC2 instance which syncs the directories from an S3 bucket to the EC2 Instance periodically(Using Cron Job). I have a parent directory in the root of ec2 instance (content-directory) and inside of that I have created the following directory structure.

[image: Folder Structure]

Now I have created another python script which watches the Incoming folder using python's watchdog library and for every incoming file it triggers a loader process which takes the file as input and starts inserting into the database(Aurora).

As soon as the loader process starts, I need to move this file to InProcess folder (which I have tried using shutil, os modules) . But every time , I'm getting the below error.

[image]

Out of 8 files I have in the Incoming folder, once a file was moved to InProcess folder without any issues. (It happened only once.)

I suspect this is because, as soon as a file syncs into the directory(Incoming) using watchdog, it triggers a file created event and the file might not have yet completely downloaded.

Any idea how to fix this??

Also, any suggestions on how to move the file from InProcess to Completed folder once the loader completes it's execution.

Note: A loader can take from minutes to hours to complete and hence I'm running it as a background process in EC2 instance.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import subprocess
import os
import re
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
import time

PARENT_DIRECTORY = 'content-directory'

def loader(input_key, output_key):
    return ["nohup", "python3", "loader.py", "content-directory/Incoming/{}".format(input_key), "-o", "content-directory/Outputs/{}.txt".format(output_key)]

class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = PARENT_DIRECTORY + '/Incoming/'

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print ("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        elif event.event_type == 'created':
                key = event.src_path
                key = key[key.startswith('content-directory/Incoming/') and len('content-directory/Incoming/'):]
                input_key = '.'.join(key.split('.')[:2])
                output_key = '.'.join(key.split('.')[:1])

                print('############################################## - Start')

                print ("Received created event - {}.".format(input_key))

                process = subprocess.Popen(loader(input_key, output_key), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                
                # shutil.move(PARENT_DIRECTORY + 'Incoming/' + input_key, PARENT_DIRECTORY + 'InProcess/' + input_key)
                
                # os.rename(os.path.join(PARENT_DIRECTORY , 'Incoming',  input_key), os.path.join(PARENT_DIRECTORY , 'InProcess' , input_key))
                # source_path = PARENT_DIRECTORY + '/Incoming/' + input_key
                # dest_path = PARENT_DIRECTORY + '/InProcess/' + input_key
                # shutil.move(source_path, dest_path)
                
                print('Invoked loader process for Incoming File {}'.format(input_key))
                
                print('Moving file {0} to InProcess/{0}'.format(input_key))
                
                time.sleep(2)

                subprocess.Popen(["mv", "content-directory/Incoming/{}".format(input_key), "content-directory/InProcess/{}".format(input_key)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

                print('File {0} moved to InProcess/{0}'.format(input_key))

                print('########################################### - End')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

Commented Lines above are the things I tried first.

Comment: How does the Python script sync the files from S3 to EC2? How is the second Python script "moving" the files to a sub-folder? Can you show us the code that is generating the error? The error message is saying that the (presumably input) file does not exist -- does it exist?

Comment: I'm invoking AWS S3 CLI commands via python script which does the syncing. The second file watches the folder and as soon as it encounters a new file, it triggers off the loader process and it is supposed to move the file from Incoming to InProcess folder. Also the file exists in Incoming folder.

Comment: I have introduced some delay using time.sleep() and it's working fine now. But Is there any way it can be done without adding delays?

Comment: It sounds like the watchdog is accessing the file before the content has been fully downloaded. This would probably happen more with larger files. A safer method would be to change the flow such that it runs the sync, and _then_ triggers the second script. This way, the first process will be fully finished before the second process starts.